# How to find all match values in xml file and replace with new values via groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have a file.xml:

```
<m:id>
  <m:DomName>CORP/HUB</m:DoName>
  <m:id>01900397531030901-01</m:id>
</m:id>
<otm:Refnum>
  <m:RefnumQualifierGid>
    <m:id>
      <m:DomName>COR</m:DomName>
      <m:id>EVENT</m:id>
    </m:id>
  </m:RefnumQualifierid>
    <m:RefnumValue>01900397531030901</m:RefnumValue>
</otm:Refnum>
```

I need to find all "01900397531030901" and replace them with "custom text" and generate the new XML file.

Comment: You can either read the file line by line, or read it as a whole string. Create a regex for what you want to find and use a `replace` method. Then rewrite the file. Please edit/repost with some code once you have given it a try yourself.

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: Have you [tried](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) ?

Comment: Can you post your failed attempt? Don't use regex and `replace`  ou_ryperd has given you the correct direction

Comment: The challenge here is in the XML a lot of different nodes.

For example: <m:id> have a different value, so if will use:

`def newNode = response.value.m:id` it will replace value even if there is no "01900397531030901"

Comment: if there is a challenge in code then show your code. IMHO with this simple replacement you could use replaceAll without even parsing xml.